# How to Read DynamoDB Document containing string values and list values Into Map<String,Object>?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a json string that looks like the following in my Dynamo DB table.

```
{
  "application_questions_and_answers": {
    "QUESTION_1": "ANSWER_1",
    "QUESTION_2": [
      "ANSWER_2"
    ]
  },
  "COUNTRY": "CAN"
}
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "application_forms")
public class ApplicationFormsDbModel {
    private String country;
    private Map<String, Object> applicationQuestionsAndAnswers;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "country")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "application_questions_and_answers")
    public Map<String, Object> getApplicationQuestionsAndAnswers() {
        return applicationQuestionsAndAnswers;
    }

    public void setApplicationQuestionsAndAnswers(Map<String, Object> applicationQuestionsAndAnswers) {
        this.applicationQuestionsAndAnswers = applicationQuestionsAndAnswers;
    }
}
```

I get the following exception.

```
"errorMessage": "ApplicationFormsDbModel[application_questions_and_answers]; could not unconvert attribute",
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException",
"cause": {
    "errorMessage": "not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted",
    "errorType": "com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException",
```

My Questions are dynamic and therefore I cannot create a custom data type. That's why I would like to keep it a map but the map has to be a Map<String, Object> for it to contain string values and list values. How can I navigate this problem? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some questions have one answer while others have multiple answers? Perhaps you could simply always use an array, and it would be an array of one answer in the case of a question that has only one answer.

Comment: After reading the values from the dynamo db json doc, I need to call an API with the question and answers. If I make everything a list, I wouldn't know when to create an AnswerValueString object to call that API or an AnswerValueList object to call that API :(